# Firefox printing options within a webpage

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing, header

Is it possible to tell Firefox the margins for printing as well as what can or should be in the header or footer?  I would like it if I could leave the page numbers on the footer, but take the URL and title off the top.  I was wondering if there was a CSS option or something that would specify this that I could put in the webpage I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the latest version of Firefox (7) and possibly some earlier versions do not allow adjustment of the margins, at least not in the Ubuntu/Linux version.

Answer (score 1):

For margin size you can use the `@page` rule.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-margins:

```
@page {
  margin: 3cm;
}
```

Avoid `px`, `em`, and percent, and use `mm`, `cm`, `pt`, or `in`.

I'm not aware of any way to change what prints in the header/footer other than in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - File -> Page-Setup -> margins&header/footer , then type in 0.25 for each(etc)

Comment: Quote:  I was wondering if there was a CSS option or something that would specify this that I could put in the webpage I am working on.